# Can an MFRC500 read a 125khz RFID card?

Tags: arduino, rfid

I'd appreciate a clear explanation on:

- If RFID readers of one frequency (like 13mhz MFRC500) can read other/lower frequency RFID cards (like cheap 125 khz cards)
- If it's possible to build a 125 khz RFID reader without application specific ICs like MFRC500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to 1) no - these readers do not contain broad spectrum tuneable oscillators and receivers - they are optimised to the job they are designed for.

In answer to 2) yes, but why bother? The RFID protocol is tricky, requiring at very least a programmable microcontroller to decode / encode and an RF amplifier / receiver to communicate. Solution-specific ICs at affordable prices are excellent news - why would you want to implement something else?

Comment: Mainly curiousity...i saw a tutorial that claimed its possible to build a 125khz rfid reader using PIC...

Comment: You may be able to at 125kHz - if you put a link to the tutorial in the original question people may interrogate this for you.